# Can't Activate Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure

Tags: feature-activation, 2007, publishing

When I try to activate the Publishing Infrastructure at the site collection level I getthe following error.

> The Office SharePoint Server Standard
>   Web application features feature must
>   be activated at the web application
>   level before this feature can be
>   activated.

The Office SharePoint Server Standard Web application features is activated on the web app. I even tried to toggle it, but no luck.

I am using a blank site template at the root site collection and this is the only feature that won't activate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a bad habit of activating web application features on the wrong web app. I would double check that the correct web application is selected from the toolbar on the "Manage Web Application Features" page.

If the problem still persists, you could try using stsadm to deactivate/reactivate the standard web application feature with the -force parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I had to use:
stsadm -o activatefeature -name publishingsite -url http://myurl -force.

What a pain. it took me a bit to find the name of the feature.